# MS SQL product list with filtering

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, ajax, vb.net

I'm building an application in ASP.NET(VB) with a MS SQL database. It is a search tool for cars that has a list of every car and all of their attributes (colors, # of doors, gas milage, mfg. year, etc). This tool outputs the results in a gridview and the users has the ability to perform advanced searches and filtering. The filtering needs to be very fine-grained (range of gas milage, color(s), mfg year range, etc.) and I cannot seem to find the best way to do this filtering without a large SQL where statement that is going to greatly impact SQL performance and page load. I feel like I'm missing something very obvious here, thank you for any help. I'm not sure what other details would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an OLTP database you're building--it's really an analytics database. There really isn't a way around the problem of having to filter. The question is whether the organization of the data will allow seeks most of the time, or will it require scans; and also whether the resulting JOINs can be done efficiently or not.

My recommendation is to go ahead and create the data normalized and all, as you are doing. Then, build a process that spins it into a data warehouse, denormalizing like crazy as needed, so that you can do filtering by `WHERE` clauses that have to do a lot less work.

For every single possible search result, you have a row in a table that doesn't require joining to other tables (or only a few fact tables).

You can reduce complexity a bit for some values such as gas mileage, by striping the mileage into bands of, say, 5 mpg. (10-19, 20-24, 25-29, etc.)

As you need to add to the data and change it, your data-warehouse-loading process (that runs  once a day perhaps) will keep the data warehouse up to date. If you want more frequent loading that doesn't keep clients offline, you can build the data warehouse to an alternate node, then swap them out. Let's say it takes 2 hours to build. You build for 2 hours to a new database, then swap to the new database, and all your data is only 2 hours old. Then you wipe out the old database and use the space to do it again.